# How to interpret polynomial regression bootstrap output?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, bootstrap, nonlinear-regression, polynomial

I have the following data:

```
structure(list(Value= c(0.228881, 0.26864, 0.2746545, 0.2588095, 
0.2212295, 0.262956, 0.239068, 0.2645695, 0.270166, 0.2464375, 
0.2488355, 0.260082, 0.228691, 0.2642105, 0.255971, 0.236502, 
0.316483, 0.2635265, 0.2293235, 0.2490335, 0.277711, 0.3510685, 
0.261011, 0.2491845, 0.2761005, 0.2556445, 0.2212895, 0.2502325, 
0.251632, 0.2535995, 0.2646355, 0.250128, 0.2628675, 0.2525865, 
0.267544, 0.243567, 0.2433465, 0.262231, 0.267147, 0.254661, 
0.2522155, 0.261094, 0.260184, 0.2574835, 0.3249415, 0.2602425, 
0.2749145, 0.235879, 0.259291, 0.2519655, 0.260457, 0.2461125, 
0.3238965, 0.2454995, 0.2547415, 0.276334, 0.26388, 0.229455, 
0.375393, 0.2816165, 0.2516335, 0.245579, 0.3038465, 0.3206155, 
0.2868495, 0.2556445, 0.263657, 0.334416, 0.317611, 0.31837, 
0.3248685, 0.3390745, 0.314509, 0.3346625, 0.3089435, 0.3258815, 
0.3290105, 0.327173, 0.3170855, 0.2896965, 0.2958815, 0.297433, 
0.333545, 0.3231185, 0.3358645, 0.361661, 0.3254935, 0.296155, 
0.3181945, 0.2869195, 0.3351975, 0.3051585, 0.314985, 0.315691, 
0.332565, 0.2660795, 0.3195265, 0.307352, 0.29095, 0.29972, 0.302007, 
0.3325525, 0.318101, 0.2955135, 0.3089395, 0.3481915, 0.2785565, 
0.3471645, 0.3290795, 0.315884, 0.311812, 0.251254, 0.3061215, 
0.269718, 0.334314, 0.3195015, 0.2758345, 0.3181295, 0.3232825, 
0.327678, 0.3539715, 0.3066505, 0.307193, 0.3124935, 0.224277, 
0.302592, 0.327028, 0.30327, 0.307637, 0.28713, 0.312529, 0.330831, 
0.2510545, 0.307193, 0.361899, 0.231769, 0.297745, 0.350601, 
0.2862895, 0.337318, 0.316977, 0.2623725, 0.300464, 0.302148, 
0.321019, 0.335075, 0.3061115, 0.3245545, 0.334073, 0.3318655, 
0.3464885, 0.348252, 0.3281445, 0.301745, 0.314267, 0.3341985, 
0.3437265, 0.28315, 0.3545635, 0.3188615, 0.3351165, 0.29006, 
0.344683, 0.328796, 0.3333425, 0.2996415, 0.329305, 0.294367, 
0.3512895, 0.312173, 0.3617735, 0.333975, 0.320697, 0.317978, 
0.309712, 0.307166, 0.31381, 0.330554, 0.299173, 0.3284935, 0.332073, 
0.3212095, 0.3375295, 0.2990235, 0.323863, 0.31427, 0.366324, 
0.3212675, 0.296698, 0.3450765, 0.2904305, 0.347157, 0.3595685, 
0.3391065, 0.315691, 0.2837855, 0.3240025, 0.326163, 0.3245175, 
0.3418675, 0.2913055, 0.298335, 0.3394605, 0.344435, 0.284265, 
0.3228975, 0.3116815, 0.3157865, 0.31368, 0.3133025, 0.286124, 
0.313569, 0.3510455, 0.3255705, 0.3203715, 0.3242275, 0.343879, 
0.3436655, 0.2713715, 0.3381005, 0.3385825, 0.3190355, 0.3597505, 
0.3271475, 0.320138, 0.3115485, 0.3276145, 0.33251, 0.3437875, 
0.3158815, 0.3218285, 0.326796, 0.3061665, 0.3622365, 0.3555745, 
0.3250755, 0.321343, 0.337907, 0.3159475, 0.3190175, 0.301024, 
0.3316655, 0.3446295, 0.3135155, 0.3220135, 0.3405115, 0.3710685, 
0.2866515, 0.300246, 0.3302455, 0.3141975, 0.332256, 0.3296115, 
0.321672, 0.287862, 0.354463, 0.321344, 0.304759, 0.337911, 0.2871595, 
0.3248345, 0.3188435, 0.3068095, 0.3741625, 0.336544, 0.31421, 
0.351038, 0.3517805, 0.343052, 0.3070755, 0.3310035, 0.3682345, 
0.3137875, 0.328222, 0.3308255, 0.309383, 0.3096755, 0.299197, 
0.3684665, 0.3453295, 0.3565655, 0.3318945, 0.3180955, 0.356223, 
0.331051, 0.2844205, 0.316385, 0.347013, 0.330784, 0.326344, 
0.3518635, 0.3122595, 0.318758, 0.3130085, 0.340933, 0.337239, 
0.320081, 0.3142475, 0.34704, 0.2590365, 0.31095, 0.317086, 0.3551175, 
0.31727, 0.342804, 0.271582, 0.2907645, 0.3480505, 0.3033985, 
0.3154525, 0.3431455, 0.2930245, 0.321643, 0.3315875, 0.328915, 
0.317671, 0.2761495, 0.316245, 0.336618, 0.2994025, 0.318245, 
0.321339, 0.3258745, 0.298861, 0.3034705), Age = c(83L, 26L, 
26L, 20L, 84L, 20L, 23L, 77L, 32L, 14L, 21L, 9L, 15L, 76L, 18L, 
21L, 15L, 75L, 34L, 81L, 81L, 15L, 24L, 24L, 16L, 27L, 7L, 30L, 
31L, 24L, 24L, 31L, 79L, 30L, 19L, 78L, 25L, 20L, 42L, 62L, 83L, 
79L, 18L, 26L, 66L, 23L, 83L, 21L, 77L, 80L, 24L, 57L, 42L, 32L, 
76L, 85L, 29L, 77L, 65L, 79L, 9L, 34L, 11L, 16L, 9L, 21L, 16L, 
34L, 22L, 19L, 23L, 25L, 14L, 53L, 28L, 79L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 82L, 
81L, 16L, 19L, 77L, 15L, 18L, 15L, 78L, 24L, 16L, 14L, 29L, 18L, 
50L, 17L, 43L, 8L, 14L, 85L, 31L, 20L, 30L, 23L, 78L, 29L, 6L, 
61L, 14L, 22L, 10L, 83L, 15L, 13L, 15L, 15L, 29L, 8L, 9L, 15L, 
8L, 9L, 15L, 9L, 34L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 16L, 8L, 25L, 21L, 23L, 13L, 
56L, 10L, 7L, 27L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 80L, 80L, 6L, 15L, 42L, 25L, 
23L, 21L, 8L, 11L, 43L, 69L, 34L, 34L, 14L, 12L, 10L, 22L, 78L, 
16L, 76L, 12L, 10L, 16L, 6L, 13L, 66L, 11L, 26L, 12L, 16L, 13L, 
24L, 76L, 10L, 65L, 20L, 13L, 25L, 14L, 12L, 15L, 43L, 51L, 27L, 
15L, 24L, 34L, 63L, 17L, 15L, 9L, 12L, 17L, 82L, 75L, 24L, 44L, 
69L, 11L, 10L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 70L, 54L, 45L, 42L, 84L, 54L, 23L, 
23L, 14L, 81L, 17L, 42L, 44L, 16L, 15L, 43L, 45L, 50L, 53L, 23L, 
53L, 49L, 13L, 69L, 14L, 65L, 14L, 13L, 22L, 67L, 59L, 52L, 54L, 
44L, 78L, 62L, 69L, 10L, 63L, 57L, 22L, 12L, 62L, 9L, 82L, 53L, 
54L, 66L, 49L, 63L, 51L, 9L, 45L, 49L, 77L, 49L, 61L, 62L, 57L, 
67L, 16L, 65L, 75L, 45L, 16L, 55L, 17L, 64L, 67L, 56L, 52L, 63L, 
10L, 62L, 14L, 66L, 68L, 15L, 13L, 43L, 47L, 55L, 69L, 21L, 67L, 
34L, 52L, 15L, 31L, 64L, 55L, 44L, 13L, 48L, 71L, 64L, 13L, 25L, 
34L, 50L, 61L, 70L, 33L, 57L, 51L, 46L, 57L, 69L, 46L, 8L, 11L, 
46L, 71L, 33L, 38L, 56L, 17L, 29L, 28L, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-325L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

To determine, if a linear or polynomial is a better fit for my data, I used the following:

```
#test which model is best fit
lm1 <- lm(Value~ Age, data= DF)
lm2 <- lm(Value~ poly(Age,2, raw=T), data=DF)
lm3 <- lm(Value~ poly(Age,3, raw=T), data=DF) # best model?
lm4 <- lm(Value~ poly(Age,4, raw=T), data=DF)
```

And tested which model was best with anova comparison.

```
anova(lm1, lm2, test = "Chisq")
anova(lm2, lm3, test = "Chisq")
anova(lm3, lm4, test = "Chisq")
```

The third model yields:

```
Call:
lm(formula = Value ~ poly(Age, 3, raw = T), data = DF)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.09892 -0.02047  0.00648  0.02405  0.06287 

Coefficients:
                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)             3.413e-01  1.038e-02  32.894  < 2e-16 ***
poly(Age, 3, raw = T)1 -3.763e-03  1.006e-03  -3.740 0.000218 ***
poly(Age, 3, raw = T)2  1.126e-04  2.581e-05   4.364 1.72e-05 ***
poly(Age, 3, raw = T)3 -9.280e-07  1.915e-07  -4.846 1.96e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.03216 on 321 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.09686,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.08842 
F-statistic: 11.48 on 3 and 321 DF,  p-value: 3.628e-07
```

I can then plot the following:

```
ggplot(DF) +
  geom_jitter(aes(x = Age, y = Value), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x=Age, y=Value), method='lm', formula = y ~ poly(x,3))
```

[image: poly]

The plot suggests that older adults have less `Value` than younger adults. To test if this is representative of a general population, I performed a bootstrap and included the cubic polynomial fit:

```
boot_lm = do(10000) * lm(Value~ poly(Age, 3, raw = T), data=mosaic::resample(DF))

#see confident interval (95%)
confint(boot_lm, level = 0.95)
```

This provides a 95% CI of:

```
                    name         lower         upper level     method      estimate
1              Intercept  3.185234e-01  3.650911e-01  0.95 percentile  3.224364e-01
2 poly.Age..3..raw...T.1 -6.027114e-03 -1.609017e-03  0.95 percentile -1.759840e-03
3 poly.Age..3..raw...T.2  5.801781e-05  1.691263e-04  0.95 percentile  5.910076e-05
4 poly.Age..3..raw...T.3 -1.333764e-06 -5.369094e-07  0.95 percentile -5.276421e-07
5                  sigma  2.954775e-02  3.425427e-02  0.95 percentile  3.044845e-02
6              r.squared  5.060619e-02  1.740023e-01  0.95 percentile  6.859062e-02
7                      F  5.703494e+00  2.254032e+01  0.95 percentile  7.879668e+00
```

My questions are:

1. Did I correctly identify that a `poly(Age,3)` model was most appropriate?
2. If so was the polynomial correctly added to the bootstrap?
3. Lastly, can I state something like:

   - "We are 95% confident that in the true population, adults show a
     non-linear trend in `Value` overtime, with a larger decline in late life."

Comment: Regarding point 3, if we go with the polynomial fit, the whole idea that there is *not* a linear trend and therefore no concept for "each year" having a stable decrease. In addition, when using a polynomial fit we are for *all* the coefficients of the polynomial, not just the one with the maximal order.

Comment: @usεr11852 I understand what you're saying, but I think I'm struggling to understand how to explain a poly fit in the context of the data. In other words, how do I explain in layman terms what the bootstrap 95%CI and plot suggest?

Comment: It is a non-linear relationship between age and `Value`. I would suggest you use something like `my_gam = mgcv::gam( Value ~ s(Age,bs='cr'), data=DF)`. (And even consider something like `mgcv::gam( Value ~ s(Age,bs='cr', k=4), data=DF)` if you are willing to play around with the appropriate number of knots.

Comment: @usεr11852 how did you pick 4 knots? When I apply the model it seems to default to knots = 10, which seem like an overfit, while knots =4 matches the spline plot posted below and ``geom_smooth``'s ``loess`` line

Comment: I started with the lowest number of knots (3) and I added knots until AIC started going up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Did I correctly identify that a poly(Age,3) model was most appropriate?

I don't think so.  There may be some issues of multiple testing here because you've done several likelihood ratio tests.

A better approach would be to have a linear model vs a spline model.  Here is how to do this.  I'll fit a model using natural splines with knots placed at the percentiles 5, 27.5, 50, 72.5, and 95 as per Frank Harrell's suggestions in his book *Regression Modelling Strategies*.

```
library(splines)

# Place the knots at the indicated quantiles, as per Frank Harrell's suggestions

knot_locs = quantile(d$Age, c(0.05, 0.275, 0.5, 0.725, 0.95))
fit1 = lm(Value ~ Age, data = d)
fit2 = lm(Value ~ ns(Age, knots = knot_locs), data = d)

anova(fit1, fit2)
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: Value ~ Age
Model 2: Value ~ ns(Age, knots = knot_locs)
  Res.Df     RSS Df Sum of Sq      F   Pr(>F)    
1    323 0.36426                                 
2    318 0.31802  5  0.046232 9.2456 3.12e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Using a spline is a lower bias way to estimate a non-linear effect while keeping complexity of the model low.  Here, I've used 5 knots for the spline, but you are free to use fewer or more.  The F test here favors the spline model.  We can plot it easily.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(modelr)

data_grid(d, Age) %>% 
  add_predictions(fit2) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Age, pred))+
  geom_point(data=d, aes(Age, Value))+
  geom_line(color = 'red', size=1)
```

[image]

I think this approach, should the assumptions of the linear model be met (looks like they are to me from residual diagnostics), would eliminate the need for bootstrapping.

> Lastly, can I state something like:

> "We are 95% confident that in the true population, adults show a non-linear trend in Value overtime, with a larger decline in late life."

Uh...no, that is not typically something we would say.  I might say something like...

"A spline model with 5 degrees of freedom is favoured over a model with a linear effect of age (F Value 9.24 on 6 and 318 degrees of freedom, p<0.001).  Our model estimates that the expected Value should decline as individuals become older than 60".

Making statements about the decline specifically is...doable, but may take some care.  I think here is where I would bootstrap and perhaps look at the derivative of the models.  You could say "In X bootstrap replications, Y% of models had a negative derivative after age Z" or something, but I'm not confident.  In any case, you would just have to be very careful about what you say.  I'm not sure it would be worth it.

Edit:  I agree with Whuber that the bootstrap is not necessary and that a joint confidence region gives information about the trend, but disagree that a confidence band is a good way to visualize the uncertainty about this particular problem. Shown below is a plot of the confidence band.  Note that the model is more uncertain about the prediction in the right tail, that is not surprising.  But from this plot alone, we can't tell if that increase in uncertainty is consistent with all models from the sampling distribution having negative derivative in the tail.  For that, the bootstrap could help.

[image]

Here, I have replayed the model fit (including selection of knots, at the indicated percentiles) 250 times and plotted only the relevant part of the model.  The overwhelming majority of samples have negative derivative, but a few don't.  This plot, I argue, is more informative than the confidence band alone because we could visualize (and if we wanted to, estimate) how many bootstrap samples have negative first derivative in the tail.  I leave that to you should you find that approach enticing.

[image]

#### Code

````
library(splines)
library(tidyverse)
library(rsample)
library(modelr)


d = # Your data here

do_fit<-function(data){
  model_data = assessment(data)
  knot_locs = quantile(model_data$Age, c(0.05, 0.275, 0.5, 0.725, 0.95))
  model = lm(Value ~ ns(Age, knots = knot_locs), data = model_data)
  model
}

do_pred<-function(data, model){
  data_grid(data, Age=seq(60, 100, 0.1))  %>% 
    add_predictions(model) 
}

# Estimate the derivative using finite differences
do_deriv<-function(data, model){
 data_grid(data, Age=seq(60, 100, 0.1))  %>% 
    add_predictions(model) %>% 
    mutate(deriv = (pred - lag(pred))/0.1)
}


straps = bootstraps(d, times=250) %>% 
  mutate(
    fits = map(splits, do_fit),
    preds = map(fits, ~do_pred(d, .x)),
    deriv = map(fits, ~do_deriv(d, .x))
  )


straps %>% 
  unnest(preds) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Age, pred, group=id))+
  geom_line(alpha = 0.5)
  


straps %>% 
  unnest(deriv) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Age, deriv, group=id))+
  geom_line(alpha = 0.5)
```
````

Comment: +1.  But a bootstrap isn't necessary, given the relatively nice behavior of the residuals.  A joint confidence region for the spline parameters provides specific information about the trend.  Plotting a the confidence band around the spline is a good way to render that visually.

Comment: Also please note that in the knot locations 0.5 is duplicated. (I do not upvote cause I am against manual knots locations unless substantiated by domain knowledge. If we are to use splines, I think we should use `mgcv` and just do it properly.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The decline is a point of interest as this is biological data and with age a decline was expected and I was trying to use the bootstrap to specifically address it.

Comment: @CanyonView Please see my edit.

Comment: @usεr11852 Thanks, I've edited the code.  I'm following advice proffered by Frank Harrell.  He cites a paper from Stone (C. J. Stone. Comment: Generalized additive models. Statistical Sci, 1:312–314, 1986.) who says knot location is not as important as the number of knots.  For these data, there are qualitative differences in the conditional mean between a spline model and a GAM.  I'll leave it at that and let OP decide which model to pursue.

Comment: I really appreciate the thorough answer! If it's not too much to ask, would you be willing to show your code for the derivative plot? I am struggling to replicate this.

Comment: Cool. +1 from me. Maybe add the reference to the post so it is not lost. "Harrell advice" (while great) is a bit hard to include as a reference. :) (I mean Stone is a pretty decent non-parametric Stats lad too)

Comment: @CanyonView I've added my code for both predictions and derivatives

Comment: I don't understand your criticism at the end, because the information provided by the (computationally expensive) simulation looks exactly like that supplied by the confidence band.  If your point is that you are portraying some kind of distribution of possibilities, please bear in mind you can obtain the same thing analytically--and more precisely--through the "confidence distribution" depicted by drawing bands at multiple levels.

Comment: Would it make sense to use bootstrap to address multiple comparisons in this situation if I have several different spline regressions? For example, here, Y is associated with a specific brain region, but I have separate Y2 and Y3 variable associated with two other brain regions that I want to regress with age as well. Would running a bootstrap regression for each Y and using that 95%CI address multiple comparisons?

Comment: @CanyonView The multiple comparison problem stems from repeated F test you perform in your methodology.  I side step this by performing a single F test between a model with a linear effect of age and a more flexible model than a polynomial. If you have additional variables you want to include in your model, you should specify a baseline model (possibly all linear effects) and a more general model you wish to entertain.